# Quiero guardar un array tipo float en una clase

Tags: c#

Quiero pasar los datos de un array tipo float llamado ca "que sirve para almacenar 5 calificaciones" como un atributo de una clase llamada estudiantes y de esa forma crear una lista de objetos de clase estudiantes para visualizar el promedio de n estudiantes. Pero una vez que ingreso mas de dos estudiantes, el promedio que puedo ver es el del ultimo array que ingrese.
Este es el codigo en la clase principal.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nc, ap, no;
        float[] ca = new float[5];
        var est = new List<Estudiante>();
        int a;
        do
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("1)Agregar un nuevo estudiante\n2)Visualizar promedio de los estudiantes\n3)Modificar calificacion\n4)Salir\nEliga la opcion correspondiente: ");
                a = FormatoEntero(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (v == false);
            switch (a)
            {
                case 1://Agregar calificaciones de nuevo estudiante
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Write("Ingrese el numero de control: ");
                        nc = Formatoncontrol(Console.ReadLine());
                    } while (v == false);
                    Console.Write("Ingrese el apellido del estudiante: ");
                    ap = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Ingrese el nombre de estudiante: ");
                    no = Console.ReadLine();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Ingrese la calificacion {0} del alumno {1} {2}: ", i + 1, no, ap);
                        ca[i] = FormatoCal(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (v == false)
                        {
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    est.Add(new Estudiante(nc, FormatoNombre(ap), FormatoNombre(no), ca));
                    v = false;
                    break;
                case 2://Ver calificaciones de estudiantes
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nNo. control\t Apellido             Nombre               Promedio\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    foreach(Estudiante x in est)
                    {
                        x.promedio();
                        Console.WriteLine(x);
                    }
                    v = false;
                    break;
                case 3://Modificar calificaciones de estudiantes ya agregados
                    v = false;
                    break;
                case 4://Salir
                    v = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("No es una opcion");
                    v = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (v == false);
    }
}}
```

Esto es el codigo en la clase estudiante

```
class Estudiante
{
    private string apellido { get; set; }
    private string nombre { get; set; }
    private string ncontrol { get; set; }
    private float prom;
    public float[] calif { get; set; }
    public Estudiante(string No, string Ap, string Nb, float[] Ca)
    {
        ncontrol = No;
        apellido = Ap;
        nombre = Nb;
        calif = Ca;
    }
    public float promedio()
    {
        prom = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            prom += calif[i];
        }
        prom /= 5;
        return prom;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}\t {1} {2} {3}\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", ncontrol, apellido, nombre, prom);
    }
}}
```

Soy nuevo en la programación y tengo esta duda, les agradezco por su tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso se debe a que los objetos se pasan por referencia, por eso en la línea:

```
est.Add(new Estudiante(nc, FormatoNombre(ap), FormatoNombre(no), ca));
```

Se está creando un nuevo Estudiante, pero el arreglo `ca` que se guarda dentro del objeto Estudiante es el mismo que se declaró arriba. Eso significa que todos los objetos comparten el mismo arreglo, por eso al pedir nuevamente las notas solo se ven las del último.

Para que eso no pase puedes crear un nuevo arreglo antes de pedir las notas.

```
  ca = new float[5]; // nuevo arreglo para este estudiante
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Console.Write("Ingrese la calificacion {0} del alumno {1} {2}: ", i + 1, no, ap);
    ca[i] = FormatoCal(Console.ReadLine());
    if (v == false) {
      i--;
    }
  }
```

De esa forma cada estudiante tendrá su propio arreglo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me servirá para seguir mejorando.